# Accessing third part website-ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, web-services, api

I did some web search and found nothing for the question i have with me, so I'm posting it here. I wants to build a simple Ruby On rails web application which will be used to display the search result from a third party ebsite without any API avilable. (ex: For example when a user type a keyword and click search i need to get the response from google.com and display that to user in my application).
How can i achieve this?
I hope scrapping is not an advised solution.Is there any advisable techniques(like SOAP 0r REST API).

NOTE: The website is a public government website.i need to access the search from my application(It has no built in API for this purpose).

Answer (score 0):

Google has a search api that you can use https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview

and there is a gem available.

https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client